# Digit counting loop efficiency

Tags: c, performance

I want to implement a function similar to atoi that would set global error handling variable if number of digits exceeds certain number whrre the usual number of digits in the 1-8 range. I want to know which implementation is faster satoi1 vs satoi2

```
    int satoi1(char **ptr, int maxdigits)
    {
      char *s = *ptr;
      int cnt = 0
      int val = 0;
      while(isdigit(*s))
        {
          val = val *10 + (*s - '0');
          s++;
          cnt++;
        }
        if(cnt > maxdigits)
         errnum = ERR_TOO_MNY_DIG;
        *ptr = s;
        return val;
    }



    int satoi2(char **ptr, int maxdigits)
    {
      char *s = *ptr;
      char *s1 = s;
      int val = 0;
      while(isdigit(*s))
        {
          val = val *10 + (*s - '0');
        }
        if((s - s1) > maxdigits)
         errnum = ERR_TOO_MNY_DIG;
        *ptr = s;
        return val;
    }
```

Comment: The second function looks like it contains an infinite loop.  Based on that, the first version is faster.

Comment: What is the value of `errnum` when there is no error?

Comment: Both are _undefined behavior_ UB when `val = val *10 + (*s - '0');` overflow or `*s < 0`.

Comment: Yes, 2nd one should be fixed but I don't care about the returned value since valid number of digits <= 8 anyway. What do you mean by *s<0?

Comment: The differences are trivial on typical processors for desktop systems: The compiler will optimize, and those processors can do the various multiplies and adds in parallel, so the fact that some of them are wasteful is irrelevant; the loop will be bound by the compare and branch. Optimization also depends on the frequency with which code paths are taken—commonly, errors will be rare, so you should design to optimize the no-error case.

Comment: @OmarA: `s` is declared `char *s`, so `*s` is a `char`, but `isdigit` is only specified to take an `unsigned char` value. In some implementations `char` is signed, and characters outside the basic character set may have negative values, and then calling `isdigit(*s)` has behavior not defined by the C standard, although common implementations design `isdigit` to work in these cases.

Comment: Also, the code apparently assumes if there are too many digits, the number is too big. But “0000000000000001” is not too big.

Comment: Thank you all for your input, Eric, I'm confused here. Maybe I did not make it clear that I'm processing character strings with only printable chars.

Comment: @OmarA: Characters outside the basic character set can be printable. For example, what if the user types “é”? In any case, the solution is simply to change `isdigit(*s)` to `isdigit((unsigned char) *s)`. You could also change the type of `s` from `char *` to `unsigned char *`, but that can require other changes in the code too.

Comment: Note code does not error when `cnt` ends up as 0 - something many would consider an error.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know which implementation is faster satoi1 vs satoi2

As with such micro-optimizations, there is often a lost of focus on correct functionality.  The second function has an infinite loop, so the first is fastest. [@Tom Karzes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60790421/digit-counting-loop-efficiency#comment107554380_60790421)

With a corrected  `satoi2()`, it has a better chance at being faster with its tighter loop, yet one should profile to be sure.

```
int satoi2_corrected(char **ptr, int maxdigits) {
  char *s = *ptr;
  char *s1 = s;
  int val = 0;
  while(isdigit(*s)) {
    val = val *10 + (*s - '0');
    s++; // Missing is OP's code
  }
  if((s - s1) > maxdigits)
     errnum = ERR_TOO_MNY_DIG;
  *ptr = s;
  return val;
}
```

Still code has *undefined behavior* (UB).

```
  // Avoid `is...(negative value)
  /// while(isdigit(*s)) {
  while(isdigit((unsigned char) *s)) {
```

Use `unsigned` to avoid the UB of `int` overflow

```
  //int val = 0;
  unsigned val = 0;
  while(isdigit((unsigned char) *s)) {
    val = val*10 + (*s - '0');
    s++;
  }
```

---

OP commented "I don't care about the returned value since valid number of digits number of digits <= 8 anyway".  If `val` is not needed at all, the `val` computation is not needed.

```
  while(isdigit((unsigned char) *s)) {
    s++;
  }
```

Comment: Why must I use unsigned char if I'm sure the character string contains only ascii printable codes? By not caring about the returned val, I  mean if the function found number of digits more than maxdigits, it's already error state and the caller will end excution.

Comment: @OmarA "Why must I use unsigned char if I'm sure the character string contains only ascii printable codes?" --> Code does not then.  Yet _only ASCII_   was not given in the post.  Others might not know of this unstated condition and so `unsigned char` is needed as well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60790421/digit-counting-loop-efficiency/60791455?noredirect=1#comment107555460_60790421).

Comment: To make it more clear, the code that calls these satoi2, satoi1 will insure that there is only a defined subset of chars that are guaranteed to be positive. The issue of getting 0 digits wont happen because the function will be called only once a digit character is found in the string. The main reason I made this post is to know if passing a pointer to pointer would incur overhead that can be avoided by a better approach.

Comment: @OmarA The various conditions you mentioned are best initially placed in the post.  That adds clarity and saves all time.

Answer (score 0):

If the user types a million digits in a row, the loop (either version) will not stop at the 8th (or whatever) digit, possibly causing arithmetic overflow in the calculations.

Try

```
while ((inputdigits < maxdigits) && isdigit((unsigned char)*s)) {
    /* .... */
}
```

Comment: Good point.  If long digit sequences were common, then far better to quit the loop after `maxdigits` digits.